# Keeping try block small when catching exceptions in generator

Tags: python, exception, generator, except

How can I keep the try block as small as possible when I have to catch an exception which can occur in a generator?

A typical situation looks like this:

```
for i in g():
  process(i)
```

If `g()` can raise an exception I need to catch, the first approach is this:

```
try:
  for i in g():
    process(i)
except SomeException as e:
  pass  # handle exception ...
```

But this will also catch the `SomeException` if it occurs in `process(i)` (this is what I do not want).

Is there a standard approach to handle this situation?  Some kind of pattern?

What I am looking for would be something like this:

```
try:

  for i in g():

except SomeException as e:
  pass  # handle exception ...

    process(i)
```

(But this is syntactic nonsense of course.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert exceptions occurring in the inner block:

```
class InnerException(Exception):
  pass

try:
  for i in g():
    try:
      process(i)
    except Exception as ex:
      raise InnerException(ex)
except InnerException as ex:
  raise ex.args[0]
except SomeException as e:
  pass  # handle exception ...
```

Another option is to write a local generator that wraps `g`:

```
def safe_g():
  try:
    for i in g():
      yield i
  except SomeException as e:
    pass  # handle exception ...
for i in safe_g():
  process(i)
```

Comment: The other way 'round ;-)  Nice idea!

Comment: But is there no way to really separate the two blocks, i. e. the call of the generator and the processing of its result?

Answer (score 2):

The straight-forward approach for this seems to be unwrap the `for` construct (which makes it impossible to catch exceptions just in the generator, due to its syntax) into its components.

```
gen = g()
while True:
  try:
    i = gen.next()
  except StopIteration:
    break
  process(i)
```

Now we can just add our expected exception to the `try` block:

```
gen = g()
while True:
  try:
    i = gen.next()
  except StopIteration:
    break
  except SomeException as e:
    pass  # handle exception ...
    break
  process(i)
```

Does that (besides it being ugly as hell) have disadvantages?  And more: Is there a nicer solution?

(I won't accept my own answer because it being ugly, but maybe others like and upvote it.)

Answer (score 1):

In your generator raise a different kind of exception, that you will be able to distinguish.

```
class GeneratorError(Exception):
    pass

def g():
    try:
        yield <smth>
    except:
        raise GeneratorError

try:
  for i in g():
    process(i)
except GeneratorError:
    pass  # handle generator error
except SomeException as e:
  pass  # handle exception .
```

Comment: It's not *my* generator but something from a lib.  Do you propose to wrap it then?

Comment: Just an idea... Let's what others will suggest

Comment: @Alfe you could [wrap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) the generator in your own object.

Comment: Yes, thank you, whatever else will come :)  But this does not keep the try block very small.  And consider you have a large block of code instead of the simple `process(i)` which in turn also has this pattern in it; you'd need a specific `GeneratorError` for each of the nested ones.  I hoped there would be something more general.

Comment: @Jan: yes, but that still does not keep the try block small.  I know I'm pedantic but that problem nags me for some time now and I'm looking for a solution I really like (or find out that there is none anybody can think of).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if it works. You could evaluate `g()` into a list. I can't test it, because I don't have an iterator that throws an exception at hand.

```
try:
    glist = list(g())
except SomeException as e:
    pass  # handle exception ...
for i in glist:
    process(i)
```

Comment: correct me if that's impossible but what if the generator is infinite in length?

Comment: Right, @Jan, my first thought as well.  In my usecase it is not infinite but it takes several hours and produces *massive* output.  I cannot collect all that first.

Comment: @Alfe several hours certainly _look_ like infinity ;-)

Comment: And sorry @Holger, no, it does not work at all; the `list` constructor does not return anything if there is an exception thrown; there just is that exception thrown :-}